# ExpressionEngine - Structure styling error

Tags: structure

I randomly get this error as displayed n picture when using the structure module. Not sure what causes it or how to fix

EE version: v2.10.1 - Build Date: 20150501
Structure version: v3.3.17

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to run debug mode, I've seen it fix this kind of issue before. http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/debug_mode_for_page_data/

The debug button appears next to the Structure settings in the main tree view.

If that doesn't work you may need to uninstall/reinstall Structure.

Comment: It usually means there is a dupe somewhere.  First back up your data base!!!! Hopefully you have a backup from before this began. You have to set a config variable in structure for the debug button to appear. Sometimes you can just reorder one entry, then put it back and things clear themselves up. This can also happen when someone creates an entry and you end up with 2 structure entries with "/" as the structure uri.

Comment: Great points! Also THIS kind of issue is why people nag about having backups. I've seen this cause a mess on a site with many more Structure entries and it can become a pain to fix.

Comment: I manage a site with 25k structure entries. Trust me, I know the pain. We automate backups.